# Virtualbox on Genymotion show an Error when i tried to install it

Tags: android, windows, virtualbox, genymotion

Hi I had a Problem with installing Genymotion with Virtualbox .

When I have finished from Downloading the Genymotion with Virtualbox from Genymotion website I run the Setup then it's Show me an installation window .
then I Clicked Next until the warning window came up 
http://im60.gulfup.com/hGkPTF.png then I Clicked Yes Then 
install but suddenly a progressive bar has Rolling back and then when I Clicked to Finish it's Show me a small window with a message says "installation failed ..."
http://im60.gulfup.com/rYShxe.png
That's it and I hope from you to help me.

I have a windows 8.1 64 bit and the version of Virtualbox is 4.3.28 .

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really enough detail here to troubleshoot. Try following Virtual Boxes logging steps here and reviewing the logs to see if you can get more detail:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/MSI_Logging

Note that you are installing as part of the Genymotion install so you can choose the manual option or download and install Virtual Box separately from the Virtual Box website.

Genymotion indicates a pre-existing virtual box installation should be fine https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide#installing-genymotion.

Comment: thanks for helping me but it's still didn't work yet